# fancyBox zoom by percentage of image

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

Is there a way in fancyBox 2.1 so I can zoom to a percentage of the image's width instead of the window?

My objective is to zoom at 50% of the medium image, used at the desktop version, when a mobile client is detected.

`fitToView` is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

So if you wanted the aspect ratio of the image to remain the same as the window but zoom into the image's width you would add the following jquery:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        media: true
    },
    width       : 30%,
    height      : 100%,
    aspectRatio : true,
    scrolling   : 'no'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WHr9J/371/

I believe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Mr. Clayton, what will be the final combination? Something like `width: "30%", fitToView: false, type: "images", aspectRatio : true`?

Comment: Hi again, I was hoping to have the zoomed image at a specified percentage of its width. When I click to zoom into a image of 1024x768, the modal window would open at 512 with scrollbars if needed, but never beyond 512.